# Start jQuery "countTo" function after object appears in window

Tags: jquery, view, scroll, window

I've created a graphic for my site that displays statistics, and I've made it look really great "counting up" from zero using the countTo jQuery function. The problem that I'm having, however, is that the countTo script initiates when the page is loaded, so if I don't scroll down to where the statistics are displayed within the 4 seconds +/- that it takes to animate (again, which happens when the page loads), then all I see is the final number and I've missed the animation. What I'd like to do is make it load after the element comes into view in the window.

Apologies if I'm missing an obvious solution here, I'm teaching myself and am still on the learning curve. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is the script that I'm using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

    // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
        increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

    return $(this).each(function() {
        var _this = this,
            loopCount = 0,
            value = options.from,
            interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

        function updateTimer() {
            value += increment;
            loopCount++;
            $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

            if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
            }

            if (loopCount >= loops) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                value = options.to;

                if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                    options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
    to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};
})(jQuery);


jQuery(function($) {
    $('.timer').countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: 70218,
        speed: 4000,
        refreshInterval: 20,
        onComplete: function(value) {
            console.debug(this);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can try this plugin https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

Comment: It looks like inView is built to change opacity from 0 to 1 for images, or at least that is how they use it in the example. How would I use it to fire the jQuery function countTo for the object that I've created (div id = "timer")?

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a try with [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints)

I'm doing something similar, maybe this will get you started in the right direction:

```
$('figure.infographic').each(function(i, el){
    $.waypoints('refresh'); 

    function animateNumber(){
        numEl.countTo({
            speed: 800
        });
    }

    $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            animateNumber();
        }
    }, {
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
    }).waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'up') {
            animateNumber();
        }
    }, {
        offset: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you call function countTo  when window.scrollTop() equals offset of your wrapper..